# api-service_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setConfiguration'

Tags: docker, api, flask

This flask API structure is:

```
├─FlaskAPI
├── apifolder
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── api.py
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.py
│   │  
│   └── setConfiguration.py
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── requirements.txt
├── requirements-dev.txt
└── setup.py
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 5000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

However, I always get the

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setConfiguration'
```

when doing：

```
docker-compose up
```

So where should I put the Dockerfile and what should I edit in the Dockfile?

Comment: how are you importing the module setConfiguration in app.py?

Comment: I use sys.path.append('..')